# Using variable to concat the data in loop and then use it outside in xslt

Tags: xslt, foreach

I want to transform xml into mq message format. I tried using variable inside foreach but it is not working as the variables are static in xslt.

Input xml is:

```
<ALCSHCALCSSpecialDays>
                    <ALCSHCALCSSpecialDay>
                       <Year>
                          <SpecifiedYear>2015</SpecifiedYear>
                          <NonSpecifiedYear/>
                       </Year>
                       <Month>
                          <SpecifiedMonth>6</SpecifiedMonth>
                          <NonSpecifiedMonth/>
                       </Month>
                       <DayOfMonth>
                          <SpecifiedDayOfMonth>16</SpecifiedDayOfMonth>
                          <LastDayOfMonth/>
                          <SecondLastDayOfMonth/>
                          <NonSpecifiedDayOfMonth/>
                       </DayOfMonth>
                       <DayOfWeek>
                          <SpecifiedDayOfWeek>4</SpecifiedDayOfWeek>
                          <NonSpecifiedDayOfWeek/>
                       </DayOfWeek>
                    </ALCSHCALCSSpecialDay>
                    <ALCSHCALCSSpecialDay>
                       <Year>
                          <SpecifiedYear>2015</SpecifiedYear>
                          <NonSpecifiedYear/>
                       </Year>
                       <Month>
                          <SpecifiedMonth>12</SpecifiedMonth>
                          <NonSpecifiedMonth/>
                       </Month>
                       <DayOfMonth>
                          <SpecifiedDayOfMonth>23</SpecifiedDayOfMonth>
                          <LastDayOfMonth/>
                          <SecondLastDayOfMonth/>
                          <NonSpecifiedDayOfMonth/>
                       </DayOfMonth>
                       <DayOfWeek>
                          <SpecifiedDayOfWeek>5</SpecifiedDayOfWeek>
                          <NonSpecifiedDayOfWeek/>
                       </DayOfWeek>
                    </ALCSHCALCSSpecialDay>
                 </ALCSHCALCSSpecialDays>
```

Expected output is:
16/6/2015,23/12/2015

Below is the piece of code I tried:

```
<xsl:variable name="dateOfSpecialDay"/>
<xsl:function name="f:concateDate">
        <xsl:param name="year"/>
        <xsl:param name="day"/>
        <xsl:param name="month"/>
        <xsl:variable name="dateOfSpecialDay">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat($day,'/',$month,'/',$year)"/>
            </xsl:variable>
        </xsl:function>   

 <xsl:for-each select="/eboebo:AsyncQueryLocationResponseEBM/eboebo:Custom/ns2:CustomLocationResponse/ns2:readInvResponse/ns2:readALCSData/ns2:ALCSHCALCSSpecialDays/ns2:ALCSHCALCSSpecialDay">

           <xsl:variable name="day" select="../ns2:ALCSHCALCSSpecialDays/ns2:ALCSHCALCSSpecialDay/ns2:DayOfMonth/ns2:SpecifiedDayOfMonth"/>
           <xsl:variable name="month" select="../ns2:ALCSHCALCSSpecialDays/ns2:ALCSHCALCSSpecialDay/ns2:Month/ns2:SpecifiedMonth"/>
           <xsl:variable name="year" select="../ns2:ALCSHCALCSSpecialDays/ns2:ALCSHCALCSSpecialDay/ns2:Year/ns2:SpecifiedYear"/>

            <xsl:value-of select="f:concateDate($year,$month,$day)"/>       
             </xsl:for-each>
<imp1:ResponseText>
            <xsl:value-of select='concat($dateOfSpecialDay,',')'/>
          </imp1:ResponseText>
```

I am getting null pointer exception hen I am trying to execute.

Please can anyone guide me through this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that variables are "immutable" in XSLT, and cannot be changed. Where you set the variable in the function, you are actually creating a new variable which "shadows" the global one. The local variable will only exist in the scope of the function. It is not the same variable as the global one.

You don't really need the variable at all here. First, just change your function to return the concatenated date

```
<xsl:function name="f:concateDate">
    <xsl:param name="year"/>
    <xsl:param name="day"/>
    <xsl:param name="month"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($day,'/',$month,'/',$year)"/>
 </xsl:function>
```

Then, change your `xsl:for-each` to call the function in turn, and output the values, and a comma, as it goes along. For example

```
<imp1:ResponseText>
  <xsl:for-each select="//ns2:ALCSHCALCSSpecialDay">
       <xsl:variable name="day" select="ns2:DayOfMonth/ns2:SpecifiedDayOfMonth"/>
       <xsl:variable name="month" select="ns2:Month/ns2:SpecifiedMonth"/>
       <xsl:variable name="year" select="ns2:Year/ns2:SpecifiedYear"/>
       <xsl:if test="position() > 1">,</xsl:if>
       <xsl:value-of select="f:concateDate($year,$month,$day)"/>       
  </xsl:for-each>
</imp1:ResponseText>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Will try this out.